# Conv1d() input and output dimensions?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, pytorch

I'm unclear how does the PyTorch [Conv1d()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html) work. Consider the following model which takes raw mono audio samples at input:

```
(0): Conv1d(1, 48, kernel_size=(8,), stride=(4,))
(1): ReLU()
(2): Conv1d(in_chs, 96, kernel_size=(1,), stride=(1,))
(3): GLU(dim=1)
etc.
```

What is the value for `in_chs` (input to 2nd Conv1d and output from 1st Conv1d)? How is that value calculated considering kernel_size=8 and stride=4?

Answer (score 1):

The number of input channels to a convolutional layer is given by the output of its previous layer. In this case, it is given by the output of the first 1D convolution (because ReLU is an element-wise operation so it does not change the dimensionality of its input), which outputs 48 channels according to the description you provided.

The 1D convolution has a small matrix, the "kernel", which is shifted over the input matrix along a given dimension. An individual kernel's dimensions are width $\times$ input channels. The kernel is multiplied element-wise with the overlapping part of the input, and the result is added into a single element in the output. Then, we shift the kernel `stride` positions and do the same over the whole length of the input. You do the same with as many different kernels as the defined number of output channels. Actually, all kernels of a 1D convolutional layer are usually grouped into a single tensor of dimensionality width $\times$ input channel $\times$ output channels.

`stride` defines the jump size of the shifts, so it determines the length of the output of the convolution: the higher the stride the shorter the output. `kernel_size` determines the width of the kernel, so it may or may not affect the length of the output, depending on the `padding` value because, without padding, the kernel can only be applied where there is enough room to overlap completely with the input and not outside of it (which would be allowed if we had padding); given that padding is 0 by default, the higher `kernel_size`, the shorter the length of the output of the convolution.

To help understand, maybe you can check the following animation. It is meant for word embeddings input, but it's the same for any other signal type. In the animation, `kernel_size` is 3, input channels is 4, `stride` is 0, and they do have full padding. Here we only have one kernel, so there is one output channel.

[image]

Having `stride` > 0 would mean that the shift will have jumps instead of being continuous; as you can see, it is not related to the number of channels. Should they don't have padding, the kernel could only be computed for the positions with ful overlap with the input, leading to shorted output length; again, not related to the number of channels.

Comment: OK, so the answer is 48? And it does not depend on the kernel_size=8 and stride=4?

Comment: Yes, the answer is 48 and, no, neither kernel_size nor stride affect the number of channels.

Comment: OK, thanks so much for making it clear. Kernel_size and stride then influence what? Number of input audio samples needed to get the first output?

Comment: `stride` defines the jump size of the shifts, so it determines the length of the output of the convolution: the higher the `stride` the shorter the output. `kernel_size` determines the width of the kernel, so it may or may not affect the length of the output, depending on the `padding` value because, without padding, the kernel can only be applied where there is enough room to overlap completely with the input and not outside of it (which would be allowed if we had padding); given that `padding` is 0 by default, the higher `kernel_size`, the shorter the output of the convolution.

Comment: When you say the "output of the convolution", to you mean the out_channels? After your last observation, I again seem to be unsure about the output. I completely understand the kernel size and stride; what I don't understand is what are they applied on, and what the output is - especially the sizes of inputs (stuff that kernel operates on) and outputs (result of the kernel+stride work).

Comment: The 2 times I referred to the "output of the convolution" I was talking about its length, not its channels. The length is the size of the dimension across which the 1D convolution is computed. The channels are a different dimension (i.e. the number of samples).